# Recommending previous coworkers while new

Tags: software-industry, united-states, referral

I recently started a new software job in the US (less than a month ago) and want to know when and what is appropriate for recommending previous coworkers. My last company experienced a cultural shift recently (partially the reason for my leaving) and I know that many of my previous coworkers are looking for new work. My question has two parts:

1. What is an appropriate amount of time to wait at the new job before recommending anyone?
2. Is it unprofessional to recommend multiple people, each for a different job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speak with your manager about this and see how that conversation goes.

If your own work is going well and you have the right approach and mind-set, there might well be a good reception to more from your same mould.

Speaking about it first and the subsequent discussion will help dispel any confusion about you mass-recommending all of your old friends to join.

Answer (score 4):

> What is an appropriate amount of time to wait at the new job before
>   recommending anyone?

This is up to you and *your performance*.  If you have performed well and have earned the respect and trust of your team and your **manager**, I would say go for it.  If you're not certain of this, then I would advise against it.  There is no *amount of time* rule for this.

> Is it unprofessional to recommend multiple people, each for a
>   different job?

Once you have earned respect among your colleagues, this should be fine.  You should show some restraint and caution here as if someone you recommend performs poorly, this will reflect on you too.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend waiting at least a year before doing this.

I've worked at places where I wanted to recommend former co-workers.  But over time, once the newness wore off, it turned out those places had a lot of problems, and my former co-workers probably wouldn't have been that appreciative to end up with a job there!

If after a year you still feel as good about the place as you do initially, then recommend them.  And by then you'll have had time to do good work and earn a good reputation.